When using 'ollama' and 'openai' models in the same project, they cannot be configured with '@Primary'
Bug description
When using 'ollama' and 'openai' models in the same project, they cannot be configured with '@Primary'.
Error info as below:
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of method chatClientBuilder in org.springframework.ai.autoconfigure.chat.client.ChatClientAutoConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - ollamaChatModel: defined by method 'ollamaChatModel' in class path resource [org/springframework/ai/autoconfigure/ollama/OllamaAutoConfiguration.class]
    - openAiChatModel: defined by method 'openAiChatModel' in class path resource [org/springframework/ai/autoconfigure/openai/OpenAiAutoConfiguration.class]

This may be due to missing parameter name information

Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed

Ensure that your compiler is configured to use the '-parameters' flag.
You may need to update both your build tool settings as well as your IDE.
(See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x#parameter-name-retention)

Environment
        <!-- spring boot AI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ai</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ai-openai-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--spring-ai-ollama-spring-boot-starter-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ai</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ai-ollama-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>

Steps to reproduce
    @Autowired(required = false)
    @Qualifier("openAiChatModel")
    private ChatModel chatModel;

    @Resource
    @Qualifier("ollamaChatModel")
    OllamaChatModel ollamaChatModel;

Expected behavior
Support multiple models, such as 'ollama' and 'openai', in the same project, and prioritize them with '@Primary'.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

The problem comes from the bean definition of org.springframework.ai.autoconfigure.chat.client.ChatClientAutoConfiguration:
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
ChatClient.Builder chatClientBuilder(ChatClientBuilderConfigurer chatClientBuilderConfigurer, ChatModel chatModel) {
    ChatClient.Builder builder = ChatClient.builder(chatModel);
    return chatClientBuilderConfigurer.configure(builder);
}

You can define your own ChatClient.Builder bean and specify the ChatModel you want to use to solve this problem. For example:
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
ChatClient.Builder openAiChatClientBuilder(ChatClientBuilderConfigurer chatClientBuilderConfigurer,
                                           @Qualifier("openAiChatModel") ChatModel chatModel) {
    ChatClient.Builder builder = ChatClient.builder(chatModel);
    return chatClientBuilderConfigurer.configure(builder);
}

@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
ChatClient.Builder ollamaChatClientBuilder(ChatClientBuilderConfigurer chatClientBuilderConfigurer,
                                           @Qualifier("ollamaChatModel") ChatModel chatModel) {
    ChatClient.Builder builder = ChatClient.builder(chatModel);
    return chatClientBuilderConfigurer.configure(builder);
}

Then, inject the desired ChatClient.Builder:
@Autowired
@Qualifier("openAiChatClientBuilder")
ChatClient.Builder openAiBuilder;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("ollamaChatClientBuilder")
ChatClient.Builder ollamaBuilder;


What did your annotations look like on the autoconfig class I am getting
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.ai.chat.client.ChatClient$Builder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("openAiChatClientBuilder")}

NM needed to not use autoconfig and make sure to use @Import
